# Streaming video & audio in Windows Phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, streaming

I have an ASX stream that I would like to play on my Windows Phone 7.  [It appears](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/a6c5abea-c4bc-4f25-b747-2eae129570f5) that WP7 [cannot handle](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/349d2b86-fe1d-444d-951c-c76761cd5c9c) client-side playlists, like an ASX file.  So what do I do now?

When I break into the ASX file, I see it's actually a `mms://` stream with no file extension, so I can't even point to the raw file.

How do I proceed from here?  Is there a better option than the `MediaElement` control that will handle ASX files?

More Info:
My stream in question is audio/video, with WMA2/WVC1 encoding, respectively, running at 640x360.  So according to the [supported filetypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28VS.92%29.aspx), the `MediaElement` control should be able to handle it no problem.

Comment: Does `MediaElement` raise an error if you try and play the stream?

Comment: no error, it just sits there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually have to point to the raw file. Even with the stream URL you can receive the data bits (given that the stream can be reached via a HTTP request). I recently wrote about receiving continuous streams [here](http://dennisdel.com/?p=528).

Once you have the bits, pass them through [MediaStreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource%28VS.95%29.aspx) to get the encoded stream and pass it to MediaElement.

Comment: If I only have an mms feed, then I'm pretty much out of luck, right?

Comment: Of course not - all you have to do is work on a transport layer for Windows Media HTTP Streaming Protocol. Did you already try getting the raw bits?

Comment: well, I got the raw bits for the ASX, but using MMS gave me a "URI Prefix not registered."  So I guess I need to register the prefix and write code to handle that format, right?

Comment: Hi @DennisDelimarsky, Can you update the link from your blog?