# How to show the video in Wp7 and how can i handle the video streaming in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to Show the video in my Windows Phone 7. And that video must also be shown from the URL, so I must also handle the video streaming. How could i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Smooth Streaming Client](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/09/29/using-smooth-streaming-video-client-in-windows-phone-7/) within Windows Phone 7. Just pop the control into your page with the correct URL and of it goes!

```
<ss:SmoothStreamingMediaElement
  AutoPlay="True"
  SmoothStreamingSource="http://<server>/<file>.ism/Manifest"
  Height="98" />
```

Also, see this related question:

[Streaming video & audio in Windows Phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151349/streaming-video-audio-in-windows-phone-7)

Comment: Thanks... One more thing I want to ask is can v test this in Emulator?

Comment: @Bhavik the emulator supports fewer encodings than an actual device so you may or may not be able to test in the emulator. Also note that the screen in the emulator will only display the current frame when tapped. This means that if you keep tapping (clicking the screen) you should see something if it's playing but it won't be like watching the actual movie. You'll need to test on an actual device for that.

Comment: Do we need IIS Smooth streaming to be installed on the web server?